# Android Studio Import Google Play Services Error

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I am trying to import a project into android studio but I keep getting this error. The project looks like it was originally codded on a mac by looking at the path. I am on windows 8.1. To my understanding its looking along the mac path which doesn't exist in my case. Is there a way I can change that path?

my path for the google play lib is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib

Error Message:

> Project The Restaurant App:C:\The Restaurant App\project.properties:
>   Library reference
>   ..........\Applications\adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130917\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib
>   could not be found
>   Path is C:\The Restaurant
>   App..........\Applications\adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130917\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib
>   which resolves to
>   C:\Applications\adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130917\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib

Answer (score 0):

iImport the google playservices to your workspace and the project too ,both the library and the project should be on the same place while you are adding the library reference to your project ,

as for such Error i would rather suggest you to work with Eclipse or download ADT bundle from android site, because

Android studios is not so big enough to handle such errors it  keeps on loading gradle every time and creates such errors

Comment: Okay I copied the google lib folder to the project folder also but still keep getting the same error?

Comment: not to the project folder these both folders must be on the same place as C://desktop/yourproject and c://desktop/googleplay

Comment: have your project and the library same target SDK as both must have the same target SDK

Comment: have you modified build gradle file as this 

....... dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77' 
 }

Comment: Do you see how the error is telling me its looking for a path in a mac os. I have windows. Do you think I need to change that in a file in my project somewhere?

Comment: or 
Go to File -> Project Structure -> Select Project Settings -> Select 'Dependencies' Tab Click '+' -> 1.Library Dependencies -> Select com.google.android.gms:play-services:+

Comment: No I have not done anything in the graddle. I dont even know how. I purchased this premade app source code online and am just trying to get it to work.

Comment: It wont let me add the project at all so i cant do that right?

Comment: android is not that much strong to hold such error i would rather prefer you to install Eclipse you can find many people to help you  in eclipse that is why im using eclipse

Comment: which android studio version you are using i got this help from google it says This is a bug in Android Studio and fixed for the next release(0.4.3)

Comment: Newest one, just downloaded it tonight

Comment: Okay im going to get eclipse

Comment: yah thats good if you get anyproblem using eclipse you can ask me anytime ... thanks...

Comment: Im sorry but how do i give you rep